# Get argument from Dropdown menu of Notebook

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, pyspark

I create a 'dropdown' menu in the notebook and tried to use it to update the graph from display function.

I can use it in the filter function.

```py
display(df.filter(df.year == getArgument("Year"))
```

However, when I tried to use it in the select statement, it started to not work.

```py
display(df.select(getArgument("Year"))
```

Do you know why?

Comment: I have both year column and each year as column. For example, the 'year' column has value from 2000 to 2008 and I have 9 columns, 2000 thru 2008.

Comment: Umm, may be check if there is no type mismatch between the returned value vs the column names i.e `str` v/s `int` , just guessing

Comment: This will not work as "select(getArgument("Year")" return a value from dropdown whereas select statement needs a column name from a data frame.